# jarsigner returns java.lang.NullPointerException error when resigning android app

Tags: java, android, robotium, jarsigner

I want to get the same functionality in a script I'm writing as re-sign.jar (a simple app that allows you to resign android apps for testing and debugging).

To do this, I'm following the these instructions:

```
Un-­‐zip the apk file
­Delete the META-­‐INF folder
Re-­‐zip the apk file
In Dos prompt /Command prompt
> jarsigner -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android ApplicationToTest.apk androiddebugkey
> zipalign 4 ApplicationToTest.apk TempApplicationToTest.apk

Then rename TempApplicationToTest.apk to ApplicationToTest.apk
```

What kills me is when I get to the 'jarsigner' part, I get the error

```
jarsigner error: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I can run the re-signer.jar fine so I don't think I'm missing anything, and I have all the permissions to boot.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... Figured that out.  When I was zipping the file it put contents of the file a directory down.  It was returning null because it couldn't find the app files (manifest and such).  I feel dumb.